# Return the first divisible number from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a function:

```
function findDivisibleBy(array, num) {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % num == 0 && array[i] != 0) {
            return array[i]
        } else {
            return ('No valid number found!')
        }
    }
}
```

I must return the first number in the array that is divisible by the num paramater, and that number can't be 0. The way i'm doing it is not working.

Comment: You need to return the no valid number found only after you’ve looked at all the numbers. Here you return after the first number either way.

Comment: @mark meyer is correct,
You need to return not found statement after for loop

Answer (score 2):

```
function findDivisibleBy(array, num) {
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] % num == 0 && array[i] != 0) {
                return array[i]
            } 
        }
        return ('No valid number found!') 
}
```

The else part is making your function return if the condition isn't met for the first item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findDivisibleBy(array, num) {
  for (let n of array) {
    if (n % num == 0 && n != 0) {
      return n
    }
  }
  return ('No valid number found!')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple code:

```
function findDivisibleBy(array, num) {
    return array.find(x => x % num === 0 && x !== 0) || 'No valid number found!'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find` method and check for `null` before returning value.

```js
const findDivisibleBy = (array, num) =>
  array.find((val) => val % num === 0 && val !== 0) ?? "No valid number found!";

const input = [3, 0, 4, 5, 8];

console.log(findDivisibleBy(input, 2));
console.log(findDivisibleBy(input, 9));
```